# Übersetzung von "in July next year"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage, time

> The event will be held **in July next year**.

Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> (a) Die Veranstaltung wird **im Juli nächstes Jahr** stattfinden.
>
> (b) Die Veranstaltung wird **im Juli vom nächsten Jahr** stattfinden.
>
> (c) Die Veranstaltung wird **im Juli nächstes Jahres** stattfinden.
>
> (d) Die Veranstaltung wird **nächstes Jahr im Juli** stattfinden.
>
> (e) Die Veranstaltung wird **im Juli nächsten Jahres** stattfinden.
>
> (f) Die Veranstaltung wird **im Juli des nächsten Jahres** stattfinden.

Meinem Verständnis nach ist (d) richtig, aber ob (a), (b), (c), (e) oder (f) überhaupt funktionieren, bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Comment: Wenn die Veranstaltung regelmäßig stattfindet, kann die Formulierung (d) auch bedeuten, dass die Veranstaltung sonst immer im August stattfindet, aber nächstes Jahr ausnahmsweise im Juli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) Richtig und verständlich, aber unüblich; man nennt tendenziell die größere Zeiteinheit zuerst.

(b) Richtig, aber schwerfällig; "vom" wird hier vermieden.

(c) ist falsch flektiert und daher unschön. Korrekt ist: "im Juli nächsten Jahres"

(d) würde am häufigsten verwendet.

Ich selbst würde einfach sagen "(im) nächsten Juli".

Answer (score 4):

Die Kurzfassung

> … im nächsten Juli …

kann missverständlich sein, insbesondere wenn sie im Frühling verwendet wird.

Die Ausdrücke

> … im nächsten Jahr im Juli …
>
> … im Juli nächsten Jahres …
>
> … nächstes Jahr im Juli …

sind eindeutig und werden in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* (für das Beispiel mit *Herbst* statt mit *Juli*) von der Dudenredaktion empfohlen.

Comment: @Loong Aus welchem Dudenband entstammt das? Ist es *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*? (Nicht, dass es superwichtig ist, aber ich möchte das nur als Referenz haben.)

Comment: @boaten: Ja, Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 7. Aufl. Mannheim 2011, Lemma: nächst (2)

Comment: Mir persönlich stößt es bei der 2. Form sauer auf. ... im Jule DES nächsten Jahres ... scheint mir subjektiv angemessener.